# JDBC and Database Integration Error

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I Have been trying to alter information of my database to something different, for example in the database code there is 50 bits of information going in to the STATES values and when i run my JDBC code with it to return the how many rows of information there is, it works and returns 50 rows. 
But i want to lower this number from 50 to say 30, but an error occurs and i don't know how to do this without an error occurring. It is probably something so basic but i cannot find out how to do it, without an error occurring.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, i am sorry if it is hard to understand exactly what i am asking for, but that is the best way that i can explain it

I had to cut alot of the rest of the code because it looks extremely messy on this.
Here is bit of the database code that i am having trouble with:

```
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL NULLS FIRST TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL LONGVAR IS LOB FALSE
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 20
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT FALSE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 1
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 200
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC

CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.EXPLORERS(EXPLORERID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50),LASTNAME VARCHAR(50),DOB DATE,EMAIL VARCHAR(100),ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),CITY VARCHAR(50),STATE VARCHAR(2),ZIPCODE VARCHAR(10),USERNAME VARCHAR(15),PASSWORD VARCHAR(10),TOURS VARCHAR(29),BIO VARCHAR(4096))
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.EXPLORERS ALTER COLUMN EXPLORERID RESTART WITH 4

CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.STATES(STATEID VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,STATENAME VARCHAR(29)

ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC

INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('AK','Alaska')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('AL','Alabama')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('AR','Arkansas')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('AZ','Arizona')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('CA','California')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('CO','Colorado')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('CT','Connecticut')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('DC','District of Columbia')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('DE','Delaware')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('FL','Florida')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('GA','Georgia')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('HI','Hawaii')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('IA','Iowa')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('ID','Idaho')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('IL','Illinois')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('IN','Indiana')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('KA','Kansas')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('KY','Kentucky')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('LA','Louisiana')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('MA','Massachusetts')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('MD','Maryland')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('ME','Maine')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('MI','Michigan')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('MN','Minnesota')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('MO','Missouri')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('MT','Montana')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('NC','North Carolina')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('ND','North Dakota')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('NE','Nebraska')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('NH','New Hampshire')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('NJ','New Jersey')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('NM','New Mexico')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('NV','Nevada')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('NY','New York')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('OH','Ohio')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('OK','Oklahoma')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('OR','Oregon')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('PA','Pennsylvania')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('RI','Rhode Island')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('SC','South Carolina')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('SD','South Dakota')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('TN','Tennessee')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('TX','Texas')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('UT','Utah')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('VA','Virginia')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('VT','Vermont')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('WA','Washington')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('WI','Wisconsin')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('WV','West Virginia')
INSERT INTO STATES VALUES('WY','Wyoming')
```

Then here is the Java Integration Code:

```
package Java.JDBC.Beginners;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

     try (
         Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.HSQLDB);
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT stateId, stateName FROM STATES");

     )  {

         rs.last();
         System.out.print("Number of rows: " + rs.getRow());

        // System.out.println("Connected!");
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         DBUtil.processException(e);
     }



    }

}



package Java.JDBC.Beginners;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBUtil {

      private static final String USERNAME = "dbuser";
      private static final String PASSWORD = "mypassword";
      private static final String H_CONN_STRING = 
              "jdbc:hsqldb:data/explorecalifornia";
      private static final String M_CONN_STRING = 
              "jdbc:mysql://localhost/explorecalifornia";

   public static Connection getConnection(DBType dbType) throws SQLException {

    switch (dbType) {
    case MYSQL:
        return DriverManager.getConnection(M_CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    case HSQLDB:
        return DriverManager.getConnection(H_CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    default:
        return null;
     }

   }
   public static void processException(SQLException e) {
       System.err.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
       System.err.println("Error code: " + e.getErrorCode() );
       System.err.println("SQL state: " + e.getSQLState());

   }

}
```

The error it is giving me is:

```
2015-07-17T00:29:59.004+0100  SEVERE  readExistingData failed
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readExistingData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Java.JDBC.Beginners.DBUtil.getConnection(DBUtil.java:23)
    at Java.JDBC.Beginners.Main.main(Main.java:14)

2015-07-17T00:29:59.011+0100  WARNING  Script processing failure
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: 113 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readExistingData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Java.JDBC.Beginners.DBUtil.getConnection(DBUtil.java:23)
    at Java.JDBC.Beginners.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more

2015-07-17T00:29:59.126+0100  SEVERE  could not reopen database
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: 113 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readExistingData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Java.JDBC.Beginners.DBUtil.getConnection(DBUtil.java:23)
    at Java.JDBC.Beginners.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more

Error message: error in script file line: 113 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file: 
Error code: -25
SQL state: S1000
```

If this is confusing please let me know and i will try and explain it better!

Comment: If you want to _alter_ the data in the DB, you need to either use SQL `DELETE` (for removing rows) or `UPDATE` (for changing the values). I don't see you doing any data manipulation in the code you've posted; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This error is thrown by HSQLDB. Please check the .script file that you have copied and copy line 113 which is causing trouble. Note you are not supposed to edit and change the .script file yourself, as the database will do it.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the script file directly. If you want to remove rows from a table, use a `DELETE` statement using your favorite SQL tool

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "limit from 50 to 30", If you want only 30 states returned, change the query here

`ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT stateId, stateName FROM STATES LIMIT 30");`

Also post the error that you mentioned you're getting

Comment: I don't want to limit as such, but i just want to know why i couldn't change the database information in the states value, when i took out 5 or more states out of it. I just want to know how i could change this and why it is giving me this error. Normally i can go to it and edit information with out an error and mess with it but i cant with this for some reason. I Put the error that occurred up now in the question. Thank you so much for your reply, it really is appreciated!